# php arrays iterate one array over other and merge them to get the final array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I have these two arrays and I want to iterate/merge them. Here's my code:

```
$userConfigArray = array(
                        array(
                                'country'=>'USA',
                                'bowieServer'=>$bowieSrvUSA,
                                'RMXserver'=>$rmxSrvUSA,
                              ),

                        array(
                                'country'=>'GBR',
                                'bowieServer'=>$bowieSrvEU,
                                'RMXserver'=>$rmxSrvEU,
                              ),

        );

$browseConfigArray = array(
                        array(
                                'opt' => '3',
                                'browseMax'=>'1',
                                'format'=>'xml',
                             ),
                        array(
                                'opt' => '4,5',
                                'browseMax'=>'1',
                                'format'=>'xml',
                             ),
                );
```

I want my final output to be like:

```
array(
                        array(
                                'opt' => '3',
                                'browseMax'=>'1',
                                'format'=>'xml',
                                'country'=>'USA',
                                'bowieServer'=>$bowieSrvUSA,
                                'RMXserver'=>$rmxSrvUSA,
                             ),
                        array(
                                'opt' => '4,5',
                                'browseMax'=>'1',
                                'format'=>'xml',
                                'country'=>'USA',
                                'bowieServer'=>$bowieSrvUSA,
                                'RMXserver'=>$rmxSrvUSA,

                             ),
                        array(
                                'opt' => '3',
                                'browseMax'=>'1',
                                'format'=>'xml',
                                'country'=>'GBR',
                                'bowieServer'=>$bowieSrvEU,
                                'RMXserver'=>$rmxSrvEU,
                        ),
                        array(
                                'opt' => '4,5',
                                'browseMax'=>'1',
                                'format'=>'xml',
                                'country'=>'GBR',
                                'bowieServer'=>$bowieSrvEU,
                                'RMXserver'=>$rmxSrvEU,
                        ),
                );
```

Comment: cool. did you have a question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
function array_merge_subitems($arr1, $arr2) {
    $offset = 0;
    $result = array();
    while (isset($arr1[$offset]) && isset($arr2[$offset])) {
        $r1 = (isset($arr1[$offset])) ? $arr1[$offset] : array();
        $r2 = (isset($arr2[$offset])) ? $arr2[$offset] : array();
        $result[] = array_merge($r1, $r2);

        $offset++;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, it gives me the error sayingPHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for testParent::getBrowseConfigArrayTests() in /Users/mkothari/Zend/1QA/apiAutomation/trunk/tests/testParent.php on line 86

Comment: @user2118095 this error have nothing to do with lucasvscn code!

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through multidimensional arrays, use array_walk php function with callback function.

```
array_walk(array &$input , callable $funcname [, mixed $userdata = NULL ]);
```

Solution :

```
<?php
$browserConfigArray = 
    array(array('opt' => '3', 'browseMax'=>'1', 'format'=>'xml'), 
          array('opt' =>'4.5', 'browseMax'=>'2', 'format'=>'json')
    );
$userConfigArray = array(
       array('country'=>'USA', 'bowieServer'=>'USA', 'RMXserver'=>'1'),
       array('country'=>'UK', 'bowieServer'=>'UK', 'RMXserver'=>'2'));

static $finalArray = array();

function walkArray(&$item, $key, $params)
{
    $item = array_merge($item, $params);    
}
foreach($userConfigArray as $config) {
    array_walk($browserConfigArray, 'walkArray', $config);
    $finalArray = array_merge($finalArray, $browserConfigArray);
}
print_r($finalArray);
```

?>